# How to use unobtrusive JavaScript approach to call a function using anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[There are number of questions on this and I tried them out.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134845/2061309) However I am having an issue with the following anchor tag which acts as a button. Why isn't the link click event calling the function?

try 1:

```
<a href="#" class="btn" id="btnSubmit" data-type="submit">Submit</a>
```

try 2:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn" id="btnSubmit" data-type="submit">Submit</a>
```

js code:

```
<script>
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        dbdata = <%=jsscripts()%>;  
        addAll(0, this);
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cart_Test.js"> </script>
```

NOTE:

Please note that this particular js function works well when it's called under the DOM load event listener.

---

**UPDATE:**

`dbdata` is an array and addall() is a function defined in the cart_Test.js file. It seems, following script is not fired after the click function event.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cart_Test.js"> </script>
```

The order of the js:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", theDomHasLoaded, false);    
    function theDomHasLoaded(e) {
         //datepicker stuff
}
</script>

<script>    

    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){    
});
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cart_Test.js"> </script>
```

Comment: is your JS code included before or after the button's HTML?

Comment: JS codes are all after html button.

Comment: Is the click-event not called at all or is the function `addAll()` not executed ? Both of them seems to work: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kz0ny6g8/)

Comment: have you tried wrapping your event-handler in the `$(document).ready()`-function ?

Comment: @empiric At first I tried `on-click` event with `$(document).ready()`. Then I came across this un-obstructive approach as a better one. So I tried it with both document and ready and on plain function as stated above. It doesn't fire the js function. I did an alert too.

Comment: @Cerbrus Before separating the function to be executed from anchor, it was triggered by DOM load event. Right after this function, the entire JS file is also called `cart_Test.js`. I noticed after executing the functions under anchor, it doesn't seem to fire the js file. What could be happening here?

Comment: Place `<%=jsscripts()%>` in quotes. Your code is giving error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` - [ http://jsfiddle.net/JavaUIDeveloper/agp3ux0h/ ]

Comment: Well above exact code started to work the moment I removed a script that was above this code snippet. It seemed as if the programme is demanding this script to be executed.

Comment: Where and in which order are you including your scripts? jQuery should be included first, then cart_Test and, then, your script. Also, you should use `.on('click'` instead of `.click(`

Comment: @briosheje in above order, as mentioned the anchor click and function works. But the `datepicker` isn't working.

Comment: Did you check the include order? As long as the click is working you can check your javascript console to understand where the problem is.

Comment: For the question I posted above, I no longer needs an answer, since it's already solved as per my comments above. However I will take your comment to debug the issue on `datepicker` cheers.

Comment: Please add the resolution as an answer and mark as answer

Comment: @freedomn-m All I know that removing the jquery `datepicker` code allowed the execution order of this code snippet.

Comment: That's fine.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer  It simply allows the question to be marked as answered so people don't try to find the issue (when it's already been found but hidden away in the comments) and anyone with a similar issue can find the solution easily.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am adding an answer since this is how I got it solved. It could be the order of execution.

There was a script snippet for a jQuery UI datepicker. Somehow it was blocking above stated scripts which are supposed to be the first scripts to be run in this page.

After removing the datepicker script (it can be any other script, not necessary a datepicker.) and adjusted the order of execution, the programme flow was back to normal and all scripts were firing as expected.